# ¿Ocurrió algo con el atributo title del elemento <a> de HTML a partir de HTML 3.2?

Tags: html, seo

Revisando la documentación de [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a) para responder con fundamento a una pregunta aquí, me encontré con esta escueta nota:

> HTML 3.2 define sólo los atributos name, href, rel, rev, y title.

Y para más sorpresa, entre los atributos de `<a>` mencionados en la documentación actual **`title` no aparece**. Pero tampoco aparece entre los atributos declarados obsoletos.

Revisando la [especificación de HTML 5.2 (junio 2017)](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#the-title-attribute)  dice lo siguiente sobre el atributo `title`:

> Confiar en el atributo de título se desaconseja actualmente ya que
>   muchos agentes de usuario no exponen el atributo de una manera
>   accesible como se requiere en esta especificación (por ejemplo,
>   requieren un dispositivo señalador, como un ratón, para que aparezca
>   una sugerencia que excluye a los usuarios de dispositivos sólo con
>   teclado y usuarios dcon dispositivos tactiles, como cualquier persona
>   con un teléfono o una tableta modernos).

¿Acaso ocurrió algo con el atributo `title` a partir de HTML 3.2 y no me he enterado?

Pregunto, por curiosidad y sobre todo porque había leído que este atributo era importante para el SEO de los enlaces web.

Comment: Como bien dice @Héctor en su respuesta, `title` pasó a ser un atributo global, es decir, se puede aplicar a cualquier elemento HTML. [Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) se dice claramente: _In HTML5, the title attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will validate on any HTML element. However, it is not necessarily useful)._

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh Acabo de verlo. O sea que es cuestión de organización de la documentación.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buscando en la documentación de [HTML3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#anchor) encontramos claramente el atributo `title` del elemento `<a>` y cito:

> **title** 
>     Un título adjunto al recurso añadido

Y además, en la [documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) se puede ver un enlace que advierte que:

> Este elemento incluye los [atributos globales.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)

Y ahí, puedes ver `title`:

> **title** Contiene un texto que representa un aviso informativo relacionado con el elemento....

Tu confusión puede venir porque `title` es un atributo global, y no del elemento según la clasificación de Mozilla

Comment: Gracias, pero lo que quiero saber es ¿por qué no aparece en la documentación actual de HTML, ni explicado ni mencionado como obsoleto? Por ejemplo `name` sí dice que es obsoleto, pero con `title` no sé lo que ha ocurrido.

Comment: Con la nuevo edición creo que he encontrado la confusión

Comment: +1 Ohhhh, correcto. Acabo de ver al principio que, efectivamente, dice que _este elemento incluye los atributos globales_ entre los cuales se encuentra `title`. Muchas gracias. Marco como solución.